# Using R to solve an ODE

Tags: r, ode

I'm trying to solve an ODE using `R` as I dont have access to matlab

The equations are

```
dh/dt = 0.1*v/(pi*(2*10*h-h^2))

v^2 = (-0.1*v/(pi*(2*10*h-h^2))^2) + 2*9.81*h))
```

---

```
vdpol <- function (h, v, t) ( 
      list(c (
        -0.1*v/(pi*(2*10*h-h^2)),
          (v^2 = (-0.1*v/(pi*(2*10*h-h^2))^2) + 2*9.81*h))

              ))
library(deSolve)
yini <- (c(h = 20, v=0))
nonstiff <- ode(y = yini, func = vdpol,
                times= seq(0, 30, by = 0.01),
                parms = 1)
```

The issues that pops up is:

> The number of derivatives returned by func() (4) must equal the length of the initial conditions vector (2)

I'm not why it suggests that 4 derivatives have been inputted when i only out two

Comment: Please refrain from cross-posting to rhelp and StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, `ode` expects a function with a given format. Refer to **[here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/deSolve.pdf)**

Hence, if you change your `vdpol()` function to meet the expected format, it should run. The general format is `func(t, state, parameters)` where `state` controls for your variables and `parameters` for other parameters.

```
vdpol <- function (t, state, parameters) ( 
    with(as.list(c(state)), {
    return(list(c (-0.1*v/(pi*(2*10*h-h^2)),
                  (-0.1*v/(pi*(2*10*h-h^2))^2) + 2*9.81*h)))
    })
)

state = c(h = 10, v = 0)
times= seq(0, 30, by = 0.01)
out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = vdpol, parms = c())
plot(out)
```

---

[image: Plot output]